Dictionary Comprehension with Pandas Data Frame, how to get all occurrences of a match?
name,age
ben,28
laura,29
tom,28
The above is the structure of my CSV file.
my_dict = {row.age: row for (index, row) in data.iterrows()} 

When I print(my_dict) I only see Tom and not Ben, why is one getting overwritten by the next and how can I re-write my code to see all of the data reflected in this particular key:value format?

so you have a dataframe that you want to be a dictionary?
